# read and write from a filebuf using iostream

Tags: c++, iostream, filebuf

When allocating an `iostream` from a `stringbuf`, everything works well

```
std::stringbuf fb;
std::iostream fs(&fb);
char i = 17, j = 42;
fs.write(&i, 1);
fs.write(&j, 1);
char x, y;
fs.read(&x, 1);
fs.read(&y, 1);
std::cout << (int) x << " " << (int) y << std::endl;
```

> 17 42

However if I try to change my `stringbuf` to use a `filebuf` it doesn't work anymore

```
std::filebuf fb;
fb.open("/tmp/buffer.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
std::iostream fs(&fb);

...
```

> 0 0

ghex tels me `"/tmp/buffer.dat"` contains what it's suppose to.

- Is it possible to read and write from a `filebuf` without closing and reopening the file ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to seek the buffer back to the beginning before you continue reading:

```
fs.write(&i, 1);
fs.write(&j, 1);
char x, y;

fs.pubseekpos(0);

fs.read(&x, 1);
fs.read(&y, 1);
```

Comment: Why does the `stringbuf` not require this?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit  can't remember the reason, and I'm away from the book right now, but page 243 of IOStreams and Locales explains it.

Comment: If I am alterning between read and write, I and just `pubseekpos(0)` each time it will bring me back to the begining rather then after the last read element. Is there any better way then kipping a counter with the "read so far" size ?

Comment: @Amxx There's no standard way to do that.  And I know of no easy way other than keeping a counter. You *could* build a stream buffer that does this automatically, but it's non-trivial.